# Parse does't do query on android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse in a android, the problem I'm facing right now is that when I do a query it doesn't do it, it skip the lines, for example:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
        public void done(int count, ParseException e) { //skip all of thisthis
            if (e == null) {
                num=count;
            } else {
                //error
            }
        }
    });
```

So, I'm not able to get the results, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors in your logcat? Do you have the `INTERNET` permission in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
   public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
     if (e == null) {
        // The query was successful.
        num = objects.size();
     } else {
        // Something went wrong.
     }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different types of query depends on what you want to. So if you're doing a query to get total number of users or objects in list. It can be done in the following manner.

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
    public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
         // The count request succeeded. Log the count
         num = count;
         Log.d("Count", "Total number of users is " + num);
     } else {
         // The request failed
     }
   }
 });
```